# Cannot log on to Windows after deleting administrator account

Tags: windows-7, administrator, desktop-computer

This is a hilarious question but please help.
My colleague's got a desktop from others today, and the desktop has only one account, the *Administrator*. He wanted to create his own account in control panel but accidentally **delete** *Administrator* account, then **switch to other domain** as he said. As a result, it appeared the following situation shown in the screenshot. Now there is only a blank account and any username and password is invalid to log on. To start in safe mode is also same as the screenshot. Any method to log on to system now?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with  "CD boot ERD commander" You can create user whit this CD/DVD.
Create le CD/DVD on other PC and boot on your "locked" PC.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in administrator account which cannot be deleted and locked, but it is disabled by default. Boot your computer from PCUnlocker Live CD and it allows you to re-enable that account. I hope this helps!